SharePoint On-premises Alert Notification is not working after changing somethings
I created a SharePoint survey like this:

And then I created an alert with the settings like this:

I tried to make changes like editing the responses from other users:

But when I checked mail, it only show the mail about creating alert and didn't have emails for the editing:

I tried to set the alert with different options but it still did not get email about other actions like editing, deleting.
Here are my setting of Immediate Alerts

How can I get the other actions notifications?
Thank you.

Make sure that your alert has been really created, at Site Settings - User Alerts (/_layouts/15/sitesubs.aspx).
And also check all survey alerts from SharePoint Management Shell:
$web = Get-SPWeb <your-web-url>
$web.Alerts | ? { $_.AlertTemplateName -eq 'SPAlertTemplateType.Survey' }  

Make sure, that your alert template is not empty and your user has correct Email:
$list = $web.Lists | ? {$_.Id -eq '<listId-from-previous-output>'}
$list.AlertTemplate # should output a long xml with HTML inside.
$web.SiteUsers.GetByID('<userID-from-previous-output>').Email

Then, check your Immediate Alerts timer job status and history at Central Administration.
It is usually executing every 5 minutes (not really immediate, heh):
$tj = Get-SPTimerJob | ? {$_.Name -like 'job-immediate-alerts'};
$tj | ft -a DisplayName,Id,IsDisabled,LastRunTime,Status,Schedule;
$tj.HistoryEntries | Select -First 25 | Select WebApplicationName, ServerName, Status, StartTime, EndTime, ErrorMessage | Out-GridView

It would be also a good idea to first understand whether the e-mail was even generated by SharePoint for sending - by looking at the SMTP server logs.

I saw the AlwaysNotify had been set as false when I ran your script . Is this cause this issue? and if yes, how can I set this to true?

No it shouldn't be the cause.. At least on my default installation with working alerts it set to False by default. What about another properties? Do you have AlertTemplateName non-empty, DeliveryChannels is Email, EventType is All, AlertFrequency is Immediate and Status is On?

You can also do some digging to make sure that all is set (added to my answer). But I definitely would look at Timer Job status first.

I have all properties with was set as you mentioned . What do you want to check in Timer Job status? I need details to provide exactly and can save your time. Thanks

added some Timer job checks to my answer. Basically, first to check if this Timer Job is executing successfully.

I tried to run the Immediate Alert but when I check the ULS Log, there was nothing. So, what happened ?
